# Paypal Billing Plans in the Merchant Interface

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal REST API to create billing plans and then to subscribe users in plans.

My question here is, is there any way that the merchant can see the billing plans in the interface like i can get them using

> Plan::all($params, $this->_api_context);

Like in Stripe that plans are created in the interface and then i can subscribe users into them. Does this exist? I have seen subscribe buttons so far in Paypal but no plans.

Any idea?

Comment: It seems like this is one of the many inconsistencies of Paypal